# how to tell Rails RSpec that spec is "type helper"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, simple-form, rspec-rails

I wrote *simple_form* input extension that is located in **app/inputs/something_input.rb**

I'm trying to write RSpec for this. When I put this spec inside **spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb** everything was working without single problem.

```
# spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe ApplicationHelper do
  it do
    helper.simple_form_for @foo,:method=>'get', :url=>helper.users_path do |f|
      f.input :created_at, :as =>:custom_datepicker
    end.should =~ /something/
  end
end
```

Now I'm trying to move that spec to **spec/inputs/something_input_spec.rb** so it will be similar name path.

```
# spec/imputs/something_input_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe SomethingInput do
  it do
    helper.simple_form_for @foo,:method=>'get', :url=>helper.users_path do |f|
      f.input :created_at, :as =>:custom_datepicker
    end.should =~ /something/
  end
end
#
#ERROR:   undefined local variable or method `helper' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup
```

the thing I want to tell RSpec to threat this file as **type helper spec**, so I will have *helper* method availible with all the *RSpec::Rails::HelperExampleGroup* functionality

... how can I do that ??

I was trying to extend/include it with *RSpec::Rails::HelperExampleGroup* nothing seems to work

Comment: better described source code for my question can be found at https://gist.github.com/3053409

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start the describe block with the `:helper` type:

```
describe SomethingInput, :type => :helper do
  ... tests ...
end
```